# DynamoDB querying multiple multiple items in the same partition key of a GSI

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB Table "Music". On this it has a GSI with partition key "Category" and sort key "UserRating".

I can query easily as an example for songs that are in "Category" = "Rap" and "UserRating" = 1

How ever what I would like to do for example is query songs that are in "Category" = "Rap + Rock + Jazz" and "UserRating" = 1.

Is this possible or do I need to make multiple queries and join them on the client side?

This is the code I am currently querying with:

```
SongDatabaseMappingAdapter songs = new SongDatabaseMappingAdapter();
            songs.setCategory("Rap");

            String userRatingQueryString = "1";

            Condition rangeKeyCondition = new Condition()
                    .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ)
                    .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withN(userRatingQueryString));

            DynamoDBQueryExpression queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression()
                    .withHashKeyValues(songs)
                    .withIndexName("Category-UserRating-index")
                    .withRangeKeyCondition("UserRating", rangeKeyCondition)
                    .withConsistentRead(false);

            return mapper.query(SongDatabaseMappingAdapter.class, queryExpression);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to make 3 different calls (i.e. one each for 'Rap, 1', 'Rock, 1' and 'Jazz, 1') and then merge the response on the client side.

If `Category` and `UserRating` were partition-key and sort-key on your table (and not on the GSI, as is your case), then you could've used the [BatchGetItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html) API to get your data in one go. Unfortunately, the API doesn't work on GSIs.